# Form validation with jQuery. A solution to any input

Tags: jquery, forms, default-value

I try to validate a form with a generic formula that could fit to any input. Anyone can tell me what is wrong and how to solve it?

Here to check live:http://jsfiddle.net/qSzBb/

```
$(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var defaultValue = $(this).prop('defaultValue') ; // store de default value
        var valid = true; //assume valid form

        if (this.value = this.defaultValue){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            this.value = this.defaultValue + "is missing";
            valid = false;
        }

        if (valid) {
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are looping through form rather than input within form. Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSzBb/2/) or this

```
$(function() {

$("#form").submit(function(e) {

    var inpts = $("#form").children('input'), valid = true;
    inpts.each(function(idx)
    {
        var i = $(inpts[idx]);
        var defaultValue = i.prop('defaultValue');
        if (i.value = defaultValue)
        { 
            valid = false;
        }

    });


    if (!valid) 
    {
        alert('dsfsdf');
        e.preventDefault();
    }


});
```

});

Comment: If you fill the form with valid names it gives the alert too

Comment: sorry it should have been i.value === defaultValue

Comment: Sorry but your fiddle does not work. If you leave the default values it gives the alert pass.

Comment: The problem was that there is no attribute defaultValue in your input HTML markup. Please try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSzBb/8/)